# Passing OpenCL __global variable to c code

Tags: c, opencl

I'm having trouble with this sample of code from my OpenCL kernel :

```
__kernel void raytracer(int x_max, __global t_obj *begin_list, __global int *col)
{
    ...
    col[id] = host_side_funct(begin_list, nearest_point, xy);
}
```

I want to pass begin_list which is a __global variable to an other function in C.
But my c code can't get __global variable because it is waiting for a t_obj pointer, not a __global var pointing to it.
How should I use begin_list in order to be able to pass it in some c functions?

Comment: do you mean `get_color_obj` in your example or host-side function?

Comment: Yeah sorry this a host side function i'll correct it.

Comment: [As far as I understood it](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/global.html), `__global` specifies the *address space*. The *type* of the variable is `t_obj *` (in `__global`). So I am a bit confused as to what kind of behaviour the OP is expecting. Showing the declaration of `host_side_funct()` would be helpful. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), perhaps?